# Solution loading error on Visual Studio 11 (BETA)

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-2012

I know that [Visual Studio 11](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us) is still in beta, but I want to ask a question before I report this potential bug.

When I load a huge solution (nearly 21 projects and more) into Visual Studio 11 I get this error for every single project:

```
The object of type Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.ConfiguredProjectCache`1[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.Immutables.ImmutableHashMap`2[System.String,System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.PropertyPages.PropertyPagesCatalog]]]"
could not be converted into "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.ConfiguredProjectCache`1[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.Immutables.ImmutableHashMap`2[System.String,Microsoft.VisualStudio.Project.PropertyPages.PropertyPagesCatalog]]".
```

An important piece of information is that this solution was generated with [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) for [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions), maybe this is the problem causer?

Does anyone know the problem or the solution for this problem?

Comment: 21 projects is hardly "huge". Not when you've seen over 120 projects in a solution.

Comment: +1 I know :D I have seen projects with 120 and more :) But it is everytime fantastic to see his own project growing. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using VS11, you should run cmake from a VS11 command prompt and use `-G"Visual Studio 11"` or `-G"Visual Studio 11 Win64"` for 32-bit or 64-bit versions respectively.

If your version of CMake doesn't support these generator options, you'll need to update CMake.

To see the full list of generators supported by your version of CMake, just run `cmake` with no arguments.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much! I miss this update. My old cmake 2.8.4 don't know VS11... In Visual Studio 11 BETA is not full ready to convert old solutions successful... maybe later :) Thank you very much...